# How to transcode with Videolan with video filters?

Tags: macos, video, vlc-media-player

Am using this command:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC Movies/Ironman.avi --start-time 4320 --stop-time 4860 --transform-type=180 --video-filter=invert --sout='#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=4096,acodec=mp2a,ab=192,scale=1,channels=2,deinterlace,audio-sync}:std{access=file, mux=ps,dst=/Users/oleg/lsd.avi}'
```

Creates 4kb video file that will not play. Would like video clip pre-video-filtered to be colors inverted and rotated 180deg.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to invoke that vlc command, and I got a good video output. But it wasn't rotated or inverted.

But why don't you use ffmpeg?

```
ffmpeg -ss 4320 -t 540 -i Movies/Ironman.avi -vf "drawbox=-1:-1:5000:5000:invert:2000,vflip,hflip" -vcodec mpeg2video -vb 10M -acodec mp2 -pass 1 -f rawvideo /dev/null
ffmpeg -ss 4320 -t 540 -i Movies/Ironman.avi -vf "drawbox=-1:-1:5000:5000:invert:2000,vflip,hflip" -vcodec mpeg2video -vb 10M -acodec mp2 -pass 2 /Users/oleg/lsd.avi
```

If it asks you whether overwriting is OK, say y.

- `-ss 4320` - Starting time
- `-t 540` - Duration
- `-i Movies/Ironman.avi` - Input file
- `-vf "drawbox=-1:-1:5000:5000:invert:2000,vflip,hflip"`
  If your video's dimensions are bigger than 2000, you have to make that value and the two preceding numbers bigger, for example: drawbox=-1:-1:50000:50000:invert:9000 
  The rotation is done by the vflip and hflip filters and the color inversion by the inverting borders of a box. Please note that the box doesn't invert the colors, only the brightness.
- `-vcodec mpeg2video` - Video codec
- `-vb 10M` - Target bit rate. Will be smaller in result.
- `-acodec mp2` - Audio codec
- `-pass 1 -f rawvideo /dev/null` - First pass goes to trash, but ffmpeg saves the important information in a log file in your working directory.
- `-pass 2 /Users/oleg/lsd.avi` - Second pass goes to your target file.